# How to access global resources in a view using asp.net mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, localization, globalization

Using ASP.NET MVC Razor, I have a resource file in `App_GlobalResources` named `General.resx` and `General.fr.resx` with a name value pairings of "Hello" and "Hello" and "Hello" and "Bonjour".

How do I reference these from my view?

These do not work:

```
@Html.Resource("General.Hello")
@Html.Resource("GlobalResources.Hello")
@Html.Resource("GlobalResources.General.Hello")
@Html.Resource("GlobalResources, General.Hello")
```

Comment: If you resources files are not showing in the view then you need to do this https://holyhoehle.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/making-global-resources-public/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this,

```
@Resources.General.Hello
```

syntax: *Resources.[ResourceName].[Property]*

Comment: I knew it would be something simple.  Thanks!

Comment: @FiveTools I don't understand your comment. If you all want is globalization in your mvc app this is the best resource i can give you http://adamyan.blogspot.in/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html.

Comment: @Dismissile You should not tell blankly *i would strongly suggest against this approach*. You should include the reason why you discourage it, so it will help the OP and others (by the way I'm truly aware of the problems of using App_GlobalResources/App_LocalResources in MVC apps).

Comment: Sorry - Mark - I was responding to dismissile - I believe your approach to be the easiest and best solution.

Comment: @Dismissile If I have to use this resource in 15 different views I have to create 15 different changes to existing models, and then when another developer revisits the source 6 mths from now to change 'hello' to 'goodbye' they will need to make a change in the controller and the view. KISS. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

To access value from resoure file in view

Add this name space

```
@using System
```

Then display the value like this

```
@ResourceFile.Address  //ResouceFile is the name of the ResouceFile
```

This method is used when evironment culture thread is used.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

you need to refer to your namespace:

```
@GeneralResxNamespace.General.Hello
```

You can do this in an easier way by adding namespace to /Views/Web.config file
In section with namespaces add section below:

```
<add namespace="*YourProjectNamespace*.*ResourcesNamespace*.Resources" />
```

Then you can use resources without namespace, like in the example:

```
General.Hello
```