# Does Razor have support for expression builders?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there anything that replaces the `<%$ %>` syntax from plain ASP.NET Web Forms?

With the web forms engine it is possible to access global resources with the following syntax:

`<%$ Resources: Homepage.Labels.Title %>`

It is also possible to [create and register custom expression builders](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/11/29/Express_Yourself_With_Custom_Expression_Builders.aspx/).

I'm asking if this is also supported by the Razor engine.

Comment: aah, difficult in understanding what u want, but have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Haven't touched Razor yet but maybe this will get you going

@Resources.General.Hello
syntax: Resources.[ResourceName].[Property]

from:
[How to access global resources in a view using asp.net mvc razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399068/how-to-access-global-resources-in-a-view-using-asp-net-mvc-razor)

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, but that's not using the expression builder, just accessing the compiled resources assembly